# OSError when loading tokenizer for huggingface model

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to use [this](https://huggingface.co/cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-sentiment) huggingface model and have been following the example provided, but I am getting an error when loading the tokenizer:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

task = 'sentiment'
MODEL = f"cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-{task}"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL)
```

> OSError: Can't load tokenizer for 'cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-sentiment'. Make sure that:
>
> - 'cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-sentiment' is a correct model identifier listed on 'https://huggingface.co/models'
> - or 'cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-sentiment' is the correct path to a directory containing relevant tokenizer files

What I find very weird is that I was able to run my script several times but ran into an error after some time, while I don't recall changing anything in the meantime. Does anyone know what's the solution here?

---

EDIT: Here is my entire script:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification
from transformers import TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import softmax
import csv
import urllib.request

task = 'sentiment'
MODEL = f"nlptown/bert-base-multilingual-uncased-{task}"

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL)

labels = ['very_negative', 'negative', 'neutral', 'positive', 'very_positive']

model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL)
model.save_pretrained(MODEL)

text = "I love you"
encoded_input = tokenizer(text, return_tensors='pt')
output = model(**encoded_input)
scores = output[0][0].detach().numpy()
scores = softmax(scores)

print(scores)
```

The error seems to start happening when I run `model.save_pretrained(MODEL)`, but this might be a coincidence.

Comment: Transformers version?

Comment: Version 4.10.0 @cronoik

Comment: I also tried another [model](https://huggingface.co/nlptown/bert-base-multilingual-uncased-sentiment?text=I+like+you.+I+love+you) and I think this error starts happening once I run `model.save_pretrained(MODEL)`. I'll edit my question and add my whole script

Comment: Yes, please. I cannot reproduce this issue with the code you have posted.

Comment: Even your script does not cause an error for me. Maybe you should reset your python session?

Answer (score 3):

I just came across this same issue. It seems like a bug with `model.save_pretrained()`, as you noted.

I was able to resolve by deleting the directory where the model had been saved (`cardiffnlp/`) and running again *without* `model.save_pretrained()`.

Not sure what your application is. For me, re-downloading the model each time takes ~5s and that is acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

1- Remove the per-trained cached folder. (**./cardiffnlp** in your example)

2- Add this code `tokenizer.save_pretrained(MODEL)` before `model.save_pretrained(MODEL)`

This will add tokenizer information in the cache folder then your code works fine after that.